# No Event Access

Tags: phpmyadmin

[image: Cannot modify an event through Events page]

I cannot modify events through the Events page but I can through a query on the SQL page.

[image: Can modify an event through query]

Permissions are -

[image: User permissions]

How can I allow access to change events through the Events page of phpMyAdmin?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was resolved with bug #4158

http://sourceforge.net/p/phpmyadmin/bugs/4158/